# Nondegenerate random walk

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

We have symmetric random walk: $X_1, X_2, X_3,\ldots$ - i.i.d., $\mathbb{R}$-valued with a distribution that is symmetric about $0$ and nondegenerate.

Show that $$-\infty=\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} S_n<\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} S_n=\infty$$

Comment: Can you say us what you have tried ? You know, as you are not a newcomer, that it is the general rule...

Comment: You mean $lim$ $ inf$ in the left hand side

Answer (score 0):

Consider the characteristic function of $S_n$ say $\phi_{S_n}(t)=(\phi_{X_1}(t))^n$. Then $\phi_{S_n}(t)$ does not converge to any characteristic function and hence $S_n$  doesn't converge to any real valued random variable. On the other hand we observe that $S_n= \sum_{i=n+1} ^{2n} X_i$ in distribution so $lim sup_n S_n$ is independent of any finite no of $S_i's$. From this( or directly from Hewitt-Savage 0-1 law) we conclude that $lim sup_n S_n$ is constant($c$) almost surely and hence has to be $\infty$ because consider $S_n'=S_n-X_1$ Taking $lim sup$ both sides we get $c=c-X_1$ in distribution. But $X_1$ is non degenerate and hence $c\in{{\infty,-\infty}}$ But $S_n$ is symmetric so we are left with $\infty$

Comment: I have just started learning measure theory so please point out if there are any flaws in the above argument

Comment: Just a remark: Your arguement does not exclude the possibility that $c = -\infty$ (and it is indeed possible for biased random walks). Symmetry condition will ensure $c =\infty$.

Comment: Oh yes I missed that part.. Isn't it easy enough to see ? Since S_n itself is symmetric.

Comment: Yes, it is easy to check $c =\infty$. I mentioned it simply for the sake of completeness of your argument.